# QGIS how to permanently change the order of records? (Sort records/features permanently and output a new shapefile)

Tags: sorting, gis, record, layer, qgis

Hello I was wondering if somebody knows a way to sort a table from a layer and then, save the new ordered or export this to a new layer with its table ordered by a preview sort. I have accomplished this by exporting a table as a csv then in excel I would sort the the orders by fields the way I wanted and then reimport on Qgis. I was wondering if this could be done inside Qgis. This would be very helpful because sometime you begin populating a layer and you might want to change drawing order. (this is not referred to columns order, It is referred to row order)  hope somebody can point me in the right direction. thanks

Comment: You need to provide a new fid with the order you require

Comment: you mean the $id I supposed. But how do you do that. I mean i create a new column and i sort it the way i want it. then how do i export keeping the sort and change the fid $id. so it would sort records permanently and output a new shapefile or other.

Comment: You could sort the data, then replace the `fid` column with the `row_number` and save it - don't ever sort the dbf file in excel as it will break the link with the shapes, which will change your map.

Answer (score 3):

For QGIS 3.16 there is an "Order by expression" tool available in the Processing Toolbox under Vector General.
This enables ordering by a specific column and saves the result to a new layer.